# Customer calls vs Customers Call

Tags: grammar

I just read this typo in a document at work

> 6. Customers call XYZ Company to do something
> 7. Customer call XYZ Company to do something else

and realised I had no idea why it is
*Customer**s** call*  and *Customer call**s***?

Sorry about the vague tag, but I had no idea about the others suggested.

Answer (score 2):

To make the plural form of a noun, we regularly add "s".

Ironically, in the standard format for third person verbs, the *singular* (he/she/it does) ends in an "s", while the *plural* (they do) doesn't have the "s".

I think questions of "**why**" languages have evolved the way they did are pretty much unanswerable.

We can speculate that if plural nouns *and* 3rd person plural verbs were *both* to end in "s", we would frequently encounter sentences, and whole paragraphs, that had a lot of "s" sounds in them. Perhaps all those "sibilants" would be discordant to our ears. At least that's my theory. *But*: the real answer is, "that's the way it is in English."